# Выборка объектов в Django

Tags: django

Есть модель в `Django`, описывающая историю изменения некой величины для каждого пользователя со временем.

```
class UserValueHistory (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey (...)
    value = models.FloatField (...)
    date = models.DateTimeField (...)
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить выборку, содержащую пользователей и value, соответствующее максимальной date для каждого пользователя, с помощью инструментов `Django` без использования ручного написания SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Напиши метод класс `UserValueHistory`.

```
@abstractclassmethod
def get_latest_entry(cls):
    users = User.objects.all()
    result = []
    for user in users:
      latest = UserValueHistory.objects.get(user=user).order_by['date'][0]
      result.append(latest)
    return result
```

Comment: К сожалению, так получается слишком много запросов, столько же, сколько есть пользователей.

Comment: Это быстрое решение "в лоб".